# Discord API valid intents must be provided for the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am programming a Discord bot. When I try to run a node, I get this in the [CMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) window:

> C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544
> throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'); 
> ^
>
> TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for 
> the Client. 
> at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\Client.js:544:13) 
> at new Client (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\Client.js:73:10) 
> at Object. (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\main.js:2:16) ←[90m    at 
> Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)←[39m ←[90m 
> at Object.Module._extensions..js 
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)←[39m ←[90m    at Module.load 
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)←[39m ←[90m    at 
> Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)←[39m 
> ←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] 
> (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)←[39m ←[90m    at 
> internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m { 
> [←[32mSymbol(code)←[39m]: ←[32m'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'←[39m } \
>
> C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot>node . 
> C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544 
> throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'); 
> ^ \
>
> TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for 
> the Client. 
> at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\Client.js:544:13) 
> at new Client (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\Client.js:73:10) 
> at Object. (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\main.js:3:16) ←[90m    at 
> Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)←[39m ←[90m 
> at Object.Module._extensions..js 
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)←[39m ←[90m    at Module.load 
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)←[39m ←[90m    at 
> Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)←[39m 
> ←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] 
> (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)←[39m ←[90m    at 
> internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m { 
> [←[32mSymbol(code)←[39m]: ←[32m'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'←[39m

I tried to search online for solutions, but I didn't find anything. I also activated the following potions in the bot settings, but nothing changes:

[image]

This is my code, even if it is not the cause of the error:

#### File *Main.js*

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const client = new Discord.Client();

let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('config.json');
let config = JSON.parse(rawdata);

const TOKEN = config.botToken
const prefix = config.prefix

client.login(TOKEN)
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot)
        return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.lenght).split(/ +/)
    const command = args[1].toLowerCase()
    console.log(args)
    // Command test!
})

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log("Discord bot online")
});
```

#### File *config.json*:

```
{
    "botToken":"",
    "prefix":"!pgc"
}
```

I also tried to update the code as follows:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');

const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('config.json');
let config = JSON.parse(rawdata);

const TOKEN = config.botToken
const prefix = config.prefix

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot)
        return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.lenght).split(/ +/)
    const command = args[1].toLowerCase()
    console.log(args)
    // Command test!
})

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log("Discord bot online")
});

client.login(TOKEN)
```

But I still get an error:

> (node:12216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: 
> AbortController is not defined 
> at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:172:15) 
> at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:176:19) 
> at RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:25) 
> at async WebSocketManager.connect (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:128:9) 
> at async Client.login (C:\Users\utente\Desktop\bouncerBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:245:7) 
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was
> created) (node:12216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of
> an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise
> which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on
> unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag
> `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 2) (node:12216) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
> that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
> non-zero exit code.

Comment: I had this error before and that was because I didn't upgrade my Node.js to the required version 16. What version are you running (`node -v)`?

Comment: @Variable i have v14.17.4

Comment: Then you need to upgrade your Node.js version to version 16 as stated in the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)

Comment: Usually only the first few lines of the error are needed, the rest can be discarded

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First of all, never show a token of your bot, or try to change it later.

Second of all:

Try using this. Since the new updated version of discord.js, like version ^13.0, you have to specify client intents:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
```

And obviously, put `client.login(TOKEN)` at the very bottom.

For more updates required from new version of discord.js, see *[What's new](https://discordjs.guide/whats-new.html)*.

Comment: I tried as you say but I always get an error (look at the bottom of my question in the edit)

Comment: Two solutions: To make AbortController is defined and now throwing any type of error you should upgrade your nodejs version to `v16.6` or try using older version of discord.js like 11.6.4 or 12.0. Peace boy, i hope it helps, in my problem it works with upgrading a node version

Comment: How do I update node js to that version? because I know that the latest version is 14.17.4

Comment: Click [here](https://blog.risingstack.com/update-node-js-latest-version/), there's all you should now, and also an installer. Also on official site : [click](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Comment: Ok I'm trying to install the latest version of node.js (16.6.1)

Comment: Ok now it's working !! Thank you

Comment: this worked well! However, I had to follow the link posted, which led me to Discord's example docs with the latest intents package https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#enabling-intents