# How do i fix CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS error - Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a discord bot but i am stuck with such error before i started. i need your helps. thanks!

here is my code:

at index.js

```
    const EconomyClient = require('./structures/Client');
    new EconomyClient().start(require('./config').token, './commands');
```

here is client.js if you need this code part

client.js

```
    const { Client, Intents, Collection } = require('discord.js');
    const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
    class EconomyClient extends Client {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.discord = require('discord.js');
        this.fs = require('fs');
        this.path = require('path');
        this.ms = require('ms');
        this.mongoose = require('mongoose');
        this.commands = new Collection();
        this.timeouts = new Collection();
        this.config = {
            prefix: 'h!',
        }
    }
    commandHandler(path) {
        this.fs.readdirSync(this.path.normalize(path)).map((f) => {
            const File = require(this.path.join(__dirname, '..', path, f));
            this.commands.set(File.name, File);
        });
    };
    start(token, path) {
        this.commandHandler(path);
        this.login(token);
        this.mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://dbUser:@cluster0.awhb3.mongodb.net/Data?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        });
        this.mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => console.log("DB connected"));
    }
};
module.exports = EconomyClient
```

and my issue:

```
TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at EconomyClient._validateOptions (C:\Users\oktay\Desktop\heise\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544:13)
    at new Client (C:\Users\oktay\Desktop\heise\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:73:10)
    at new EconomyClient (C:\Users\oktay\Desktop\heise\structures\Client.js:4:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\oktay\Desktop\heise\index.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
}
```

Comment: did you search stack overflow? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68701446/discord-api-valid-intents-must-be-provided-for-the-client) seems to be the same question asked only 4 days ago

Comment: @Bravo i tried but i still have the same problem. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Oh, can't see where you call `new Client` at all - perhaps you've done it wrong - can you show the updated code

Comment: i am edited the question (Client.js)

Comment: so, you create `const client = new Client` ... and do nothing with it - I think you may have missed the point of class inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will explain it again.

`If you need your bot to receive messages (MESSAGE_CREATE - "messageCreate" in discord.js), you need the GUILD_MESSAGES intent. If you want your bot to post welcome messages for new members (GUILD_MEMBER_ADD - "guildMemberAdd" in discord.js), you need the GUILD_MEMBERS intent, and so on.`

So, put valid intent and it will be working.
You can also put every each of them for the future and you will never get this error again.