# Why do i keep getting error when typing node . or node main.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I followed a tutorial by Codelyon. I followed it before but now it's not working. I don't know if I just typed something wrong and can't see it, or if I'm missing something completely different. Just to clarify, yes, I saved before typing `node .` and `node main.js`

Code

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

 const client = new Discord.Client();



client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Kilobot is online')
});




client.login('bot token');
```

Error:

> TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix CLIENT\_MISSING\_INTENTS error - Disord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error-disord-js)

Comment: Tutorials such as Codelyon's are very outdated, they were made for discord.js v11. Latest version of discord.js is v13, which is almost completely different from v11 and you will find that nearly none of the code in those tutorials will work for you. I would not recommend following those tutorials. Use the [official discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/) or such instead.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, in the new version you need to specify intents before doing any work. Here's a [link](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#creating-the-main-file) on documentation.

```js
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

And your question is already asked on stackoverflow, in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68701446/discord-api-valid-intents-must-be-provided-for-the-client?rq=1)

Comment: Indeed, this is the correct answer. It appears the Codelyon tutorial that the OP followed is outdated, and is most likely using discord.js v11 as opposed to the latest version. For further documentation, [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents) is a list of all intents and the events/data they correspond to.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the case. But waiting for him/her to respond if s/he got any more errors. Thanks for pointing out the possible intents.