# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'login')

Tags: node.js, discord

My Index.js is having a error. I can't understand why.

```
const { Client, Collection } = require("discord.js");
const { readdirSync } = require("fs");
const { join } = require("path");
const { TOKEN, PREFIX } = require("./util/Util");
const i18n = require("./util/i18n");

const { Intents, client } = require('discord.js');





client.login(TOKEN);
client.commands = new Collection();
client.prefix = PREFIX;
client.queue = new Map();
const cooldowns = new Collection();
const escapeRegex = (str) => str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`${client.user.username} ready!`);
    client.user.setActivity(`with ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers`);
  });
  client.on("warn", (info) => console.log(info));
  client.on("error", console.error);

  const commandFiles = readdirSync(join(__dirname, "commands")).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
  for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(join(__dirname, "commands", `${file}`));
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
  }


client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.guild) return;
  
    const prefixRegex = new RegExp(`^(<@!?${client.user.id}>|${escapeRegex(PREFIX)})\\s*`);
    if (!prefixRegex.test(message.content)) return;
  
    const [, matchedPrefix] = message.content.match(prefixRegex);
  
    const args = message.content.slice(matchedPrefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  
    const command =
      client.commands.get(commandName) ||
      client.commands.find((cmd) => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));
  
    if (!command) return;
  
    if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
      cooldowns.set(command.name, new Collection());
    }
  
    const now = Date.now();
    const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
    const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown || 1) * 1000;
  
    if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
      const expirationTime = timestamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;
  
      if (now < expirationTime) {
        const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000;
        return message.reply(
          i18n.__mf("common.cooldownMessage", { time: timeLeft.toFixed(1), name: command.name })
        );
      }
    }
  
    timestamps.set(message.author.id, now);
    setTimeout(() => timestamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldownAmount);
  
    try {
      command.execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      message.reply(i18n.__("common.errorCommand")).catch(console.error);
    }
  });

  client.login(TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The import is called `Client` instead of `client`. So change your import and instantiate the client like so:

```
const { Intents, Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
```

You will have to set the `intents` according to your own use case, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68701506/3571248).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `client.login(TOKEN);` two times, in the beginning and in the final of the code.

Comment: still error appears