# Coding a discord bot on discord.js and i keep getting the error "TypeError [ClientMissingIntents]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client."

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

when I try to run the code it gives me the error "TypeError [ClientMissingIntents]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.". I tried using node . and node main.js to run it. I followed a yt tutorial and it looks like it should work.

Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'TOKEN HERE'

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('GamrBot1.0 is online');
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: You must be watching some outdated tutorial if they didn't need to provide intents. What's your discord.js version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord Api Valid intents must be provided for the Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68701446/discord-api-valid-intents-must-be-provided-for-the-client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `discord.js` v13, you need Intents when you declare your client. You can add them by doing this:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        // ...
    ]
})
```

For more information, I'd suggest you go here => [Gateway Intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#gateway-intents)